# Trying to get www.example.com from a subfolder /example.com into a NGINX server of mine

Tags: php, nginx, hosts

long story short:

my work station hosts file (OSX 10.12):

```
1.1.1.1 www.ambrogio.prd
1.1.1.1 www.example.com
```

my NGINX webserver root:

/var/www/html/

the subfolder I would www.example.com to be pointed:
/var/www/html/example.com

my NGINX /ect/nginx/sites-available/default:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        root /var/www/html;
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        #my NGINX web root for testing purposes
        server_name ambrogio.prd;
        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        #my wannabe www.example.com 

        server_name www.example.com;
        location ^~ /example.com {
            alias /var/www/html/example.com;
            index index.php index.html index.htm;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
            autoindex on;
    }
}
```

I found various solved scenarios, [like this one](https://serverfault.com/questions/218818/nginx-projects-in-subfolders), what I'm not getting yet is how to make sure that, when I type www.example.com in my work station browser, my NGINX points me to /var/www/html/example.com and not to /var/www/html

Thanks!

**SOLVED:** [Thanks to [@Richard Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4862445/richard-smith) ]

I needed separate server blocks for each server_name. See [here for more info about issues like this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html).

here's my NGINX /ect/nginx/sites-available/default updated configuration:

```
server {
       #each *server_name domain_name.ext* now has it's own separate server{} block

       listen 80;

        #my now-working www.example.com domain, with virtual hosts from my work station on Mac  

        server_name example.com www.example.com;
        root /var/www/html/example.com;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        location / {
               try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

}
```

Comment: You need a separate `server` block for each `server_name`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) for more.

Comment: @RichardSmith thank you so much. 
I updated my post with your solution, and the updated configuration - at first it was just pointing my to the default nginx welcome page, but I managed to solve the last issues.